# Need help making my website fit to all device screens

Tags: wordpress, mobile

Im having trouble making a wordpress site fit mobile and tablet devices without having to pinch touch it to fit the screen, any way of doing this? i did something once with some css coding in the custom css area but lost the codes and cant remember where i got them from, the site is http://www.meanteamtrainingformen.com

thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Cheers, already followed that but cant seem to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.

You could look at doing it yourself with [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

You could use [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: i had it sorted at one stage just using the @media etc etc but something happened and now it wont work..

Comment: if i use #page and change the width in style.css it changes for mobiles, but cant get it to be exactly the same on mobile as what it looks like on the laptop,

Comment: You will have to change more than just the page width probably. Specifically, fixed width elements. Although it will be impossible to make it look exactly the same, since it will be a smaller version of the page as it would look on a PC.

Comment: let me know how it goes, and if my answer worked please mark as correct and upvote (GIMME ALL THE REPUTATION) :p